# Quartz.net same job executed twice at same time in asp.net

Tags: asp.net, quartz.net

I am using Quartz library version 2.3.3.0 for execution of email sending job on daily basis at the required time of 8am and 4pm. The site is now live, and has been sending emails at correct times for last two days. However it happened today at 8am that the job was executed twice, and all the email were also sent twice. For that i had setup a log table to monitor the status of the email job being executed at correct time. And in today's log each record was inserted twice. I don't have an idea why this has happened. Below is the code I'm running for this functionality.

**JobScheduler.cs**

```
public class JobScheduler
    {
        public static void Start()
        {
            IJobDetail emailJob = JobBuilder.Create<EmailJob>()
                  .WithIdentity("job1")
                  .Build();

            ITrigger trigger = TriggerBuilder.Create().WithDailyTimeIntervalSchedule
                  (s =>
                     s.WithIntervalInSeconds(30)
                    .OnEveryDay()
                  )
                 .ForJob(emailJob)
                 .WithIdentity("trigger1")
                 .StartNow()
                 .WithCronSchedule("0 0/1 * * * ?") // Time : Every 1 Minutes job execute
                 .Build();

            ISchedulerFactory sf = new StdSchedulerFactory();
            IScheduler sc =  sf.GetScheduler();
             sc.ScheduleJob(emailJob, trigger);
             sc.Start();
        }
    }
```

**EmailJob.cs**

```
public void Execute(IJobExecutionContext context)
        {
            //check for date and time of event
            //if starttime and date is tomorrow then send reminder email
            //if starttime and date is today then send reminder email

            string time = DateTime.Now.ToString("h:mm tt");

            if (time == "4:00 PM" || time == "8:00 AM")
            {
                InsertLogMessage("Entring Email Job Execute Function if "+ time);

                GetAllBookings();
            }

        }

        private List<int> GetAllBookingsTimes()
        {
            InsertLogMessage("Getting all booking times when time is " + DateTime.Now.ToShortTimeString());

            List<int> lst = new List<int>();
            try
            {

                //Select for upcoming event of today and tomorrow
                conn = Database.getInstance();
                conn.Open();

                cmd = new SqlCommand("ReminderEmails", conn);
                cmd.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Action", "CheckForReminder");

                reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();

                while (reader.Read())
                {
                    Times t = new Times();

                    t.iTimesId = Convert.ToInt32(reader["TimesId"]);

                    if (!lst.Contains(t.iTimesId))
                    {
                        lst.Add(t.iTimesId);
                    }
                }

                conn.Close();

            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                InsertLogMessage(ex.Message);
            }

            InsertLogMessage("Returning to Bookings after scheduled times");

            return lst;
        }

        private void GetAllBookings()
        {
            InsertLogMessage("Getting Booking w.r.t times");

            Dictionary<int, List<Booking>> dicofbooking = new Dictionary<int, List<Booking>>();

            try {

                List<int> timesid = GetAllBookingsTimes();

                foreach(var item in timesid)
                {
                    //Get email status confirmation 
                    bool status = GetEmailStatus(item.ToString());

                    if (status == false)
                    {
                        List<Booking> bookinglst = new List<Booking>();
                        bookinglst = CheckForReminder().Where(p => p.tTimes.iTimesId == item).ToList();
                        dicofbooking.Add(item, bookinglst);
                    }
                }

                blist = new List<Booking>();
                bcclst = new List<string>();

                foreach (var item in dicofbooking)
                {
                    foreach (var item1 in item.Value)
                    {
                        if (item1.tTimes.dtDateTime.Date == DateTime.Now.Date || item1.tTimes.dtDateTime.Date == DateTime.Now.Date.AddDays(1))
                        {
                            //Send email at particular time
                            if (bcclst.Contains(item1.mMember.strEmailAddress) == false)
                            {
                                bcclst.Add(item1.mMember.strEmailAddress);
                                blist.Add(item1);
                            }
                        }
                    }

                    if (blist.Count > 0)
                    {
                        InsertLogMessage("Sending Email for "+ blist[0].eEvent.strEventTitle + " " + blist[0].tTimes.iTimesId);
                        if (SendEmail(blist[0]))
                        {
                            InsertLogMessage("Email sent successfully for " + blist[0].eEvent.strEventTitle + " " + blist[0].tTimes.iTimesId);
                            //Set Reminder Email Status to true
                            UpdateEmailStatus(blist[0].tTimes.iTimesId.ToString());
                        }
                    }

                    blist = new List<Booking>();
                    bcclst = new List<string>();

                }

            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                InsertLogMessage(ex.Message);
            }


        }
```

Comment: If you want to send emails at a specific time, i'd recommend a windows service or scheduled task. If your site is recycled, offline or in sleep mode (usually after 20 mins of inactivity) the mails won't be send.

Comment: It always sends. And in this case it sent twice.

Comment: Where and when is `Start()` called?

Comment: Start is called on Execute method in Email Job class. and every after 1 minute. That's why it never sleeps in background i think.

Answer (score 0):

This issue is due to executing the trigger on both the condition like 30s and 60s.

s.WithIntervalInSeconds(30)

and

WithCronSchedule("0 0/1 * * * ?")

On job "Execute" function also mentioned and compare with its datetime, in 30s same time may be fired.
change trigger as like as following

```
trigger = newTrigger()
    .withIdentity("trigger3", "group1")
    .withSchedule(cronSchedule("0 0/15 8,16 * * ?"))
    .forJob("myJob", "group1")
    .build();
```

change job "Execute" function to

```
public void Execute(IJobExecutionContext context)
        {
                InsertLogMessage("Entring Email Job Execute Function if "+ time);
                GetAllBookings();
        }
```

This trigger would be fired on every 15 minutes but execute only on 8am and 4pm.
No need to double checking with datetime.

Answer (score -2):

My guess you are loading the configuration twice, once with your ContextLoaderListener and once in the DispatcherServlet resulting in duplication. Check your config.

Comment: There isn't such keyword used in the web.config file. What are you talking about.

Comment: Are you not using the spring framework? i have given the comment based on the spring framework. show me the web config file